# Material UI warning: You are trying to override a style that does not exist. Fix the `&$selected` key of `theme.overrides.MuiTab`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to override some MUI styles in React Material UI. This is currently working for me:

```
MuiTab: {
    root: {
        color: '#284568',
    },
    textColorInherit: {
        opacity: 1,
    },
    wrapper: {
        textTransform: 'capitalize',
    },
    '&$selected': {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        border: '1px solid #CFDCE8',
    },
},
```

However, it gives me a warning on the console:

> "getStylesCreator.js:42 Material-UI: You are trying to override a
> style that does not exist. Fix the `&$selected` key of
> `theme.overrides.MuiTab`."

I tried to convert to:

```
MuiTab: {
    root: {
        color: '#284568',
        '&$selected': {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            border: '1px solid #CFDCE8',
        },
    },
    textColorInherit: {
        opacity: 1,
    },
    wrapper: {
        textTransform: 'capitalize',
    },
},
```

The warning was gone, but the style won't apply anymore :(
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: to replace the style fro mui styles you will need to implemente like '& .MuiTabs-indicator': { , and you most use !important to apply effect, it was this way i have done, try it and say samting

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL Can you please provide an example? thanks.

Comment: i have added one